# Error in LinearRegression Model while using Flask

Tags: python, flask, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I am developing a simple linear regression model for car price prediction.
In Jupyter Notebook model works fine but when called from Flask gives an error.
I am using pickle library to store trained model and the same to load it in Flask

Code that I have tried:

```
model = pickle.load(open('CarPricePredictorModel.pkl','rb'))#read binary
```

Route function:

```
@app.route("/predict",methods=['post'])
def predict():
    company = request.form.get('company')
    model = request.form.get('model')
    year = int(request.form.get('year'))
    fuel_type = request.form.get('fuel_type')
    kms_driven = int(request.form.get('kms_driven'))
    prediction = model.predict(pd.DataFrame([[model,company,year,kms_driven,fuel_type]],columns=['name','company','year','kms_driven','fuel_type']))
    print(prediction)
    
    print(prediction)
    return prediction
```

Error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'`

[image: This is my Jupyter Notebook structure]

Can anybody tell where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Accidently I have overwritten the variable `model` with car model in the code.

Improvised version of code

```
predictionmodel = pickle.load(open('CarPricePredictorModel.pkl','rb'))#read binary
```

```
@app.route("/predict",methods=['post'])
def predict():
    try:
        company = request.form.get('company')
        model = request.form.get('model')
        year = int(request.form.get('year'))
        fuel_type = request.form.get('fuel_type')
        kms_driven = int(request.form.get('kms_driven'))
        prediction = predictionmodel.predict(pd.DataFrame([[model,company,year,kms_driven,fuel_type]],columns=['name','company','year','kms_driven','fuel_type']))
        return str(round(prediction[0],2))

    except ValueError:
        return "Every field is mandatory"
```

Thank you :).